# how to use Torch to initialize GPU

Tags: python, torch

I am making a model using FacebookVideoPose3D.

but problem is , i used `model.cuda()` still when i run it, GPU is about 2-3%

also it is very slow rendring in 3D

can someone tell me how to utilize GPU to torch code??
and minimum requirement of GPUs for live rendering?

why Torch is not using Cuda?

Answer (score 0):

1. refer this [how to use GPU in cuda](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/solved-make-sure-that-pytorch-using-gpu-to-compute/4870)
2. you need atleast 3-4 well advanced GPUs for live rendering

I did that with 5 GPUs (mine is RTX 2080) and 10 core processor, still it is not that fast(I got 20-24 FPS).